# Meaning of OWL exact cardinality restrictions

Tags: owl, protege, manchester-syntax

I am a newbie coding with the [Manchester syntax for OWL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/). I need to understand the role of `exactly`.   Which of these restrictions is correct:

```
(hasChild (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
(hasChild (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
(hasChild (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
(hasChild (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
```

Can you explain it when `A` and `B` are equivalent, and when they are disjoint?

Comment: The W3C working note on Manchester syntax doesn't have a production for [objectproperty class] in its [section on class descriptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/#Descriptions).  Is `hasChild (A or B)` supposed to be `hasChild some (A or B)` or `hasChild only (A or B)` (or something else)?  Similarly for the expressions involving `(A and B)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The meaning of class expressions is defined in section [2.2.3 Class Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/#Class_Expressions) of the *OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Direct Semantics* W3C recommendation.

The four class expressions given in the question aren't quite well formed, as I understand the Manchester OWL syntax, as `hasChild (A or/and B)` really needs to be `hasChild some/only (A or/and B)`.  That said, we can still discuss the meaning of the various combinations.

### Exact Cardinality Restrictions

The restrictions `hasChild exactly 1 Thing` and `hasChild exactly 2 Thing` denote the classes of individuals which are related to exactly one or two other individuals by the `hasChild` property, respectively.  Since the class expression in the restriction is `Thing`, it is probably more common to see the versions without a class: `hasChild exactly 1` and `hasChild exactly 2`.

### Universal or AllValuesFrom Restrictions

The expression `hasChild only X` denotes the class of individuals which are such that *if* they are related to any other individual by the `hasChild` property, *then* the other individual is an **instance of** `X`.  It does not impose any constraint that there *are* such individuals, but only that *if* there are any, then they must be `X`s.

### Existential or SomeValuesFrom Restrictions

The expression `hasChild some X` denotes the class of individuals which are related to **at least** one other individual that is an `X` by the `hasChild` property.  It does not impose any constraint that every other individual related by the `hasChild` is an `X`, just that at least one is.

### The meaning of the expressions

The class expressions in the problem aren't well formed at the moment, and should either be `hasChild some (A or/and B)` or `hasChild only (A or/and B)`.  This means that there are a number of cases to consider, but fortunately some of them condense down.

#### If A and B are equivalent

If `A` and `B` are equivalent, then both `(A or B)` and `(A and B)` are equivalent to `A` and to `B`.  This means that the expressions in the question can be simplified into two cases, depending on whether the restriction on the left hand side should be `some` or `only`.

- `(hasChild some A) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)`
  This class expression denotes the class of individuals which are related by the `hasChild` property to **at least one** individual of type `A`, and that are related to exactly one other individual by the `hasChild` property (and by the left side, that one individual must be that individual of type `A`).
- `(hasChild some A) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)`
  This class expression denotes the class of individuals which are related by the `hasChild` property to **at least one** individual of type `A`, and that are related to exactly two individuals by the `hasChild` property (and by the left side, one of these individuals must that individual of type `A`).
- `(hasChild only A) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)`
  This class expression denotes the class of individuals which are related by the `hasChild` property only to individuals of type `A`, and that are related to exactly one other individual by the `hasChild` property (and by the left side, that one individual must be of type `A`).
- `(hasChild only A) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)`
  This class expression denotes the class of individuals which are related by the `hasChild` property to some individual of type `A`, and that are related to exactly two individuals by the `hasChild` property (and by the left side, both of these individuals must that individual of type `A`).

#### If A and B are disjoint

If `A` and `B` are disjoint, then the class expression `A and B` denotes the empty class, since nothing can be both an `A` and a `B`.  That means that that four of the cases are unsatisfiable.

The cases that involve `hasChild some (A and B)` are unsatisfiable, because there are no `A and B`s for anything to be related to.  There are two such cases:

```
(hasChild some (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
(hasChild some (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
```

The combination of `only (A and B)` and `exactly n` is unsatisfiable, since (as long as `n` is not 0), it says that an individual must be related to exactly `n` things, and that each of those `n` things must be an `A and B` (of which there can be none.  There are two such cases:

```
(hasChild only (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
(hasChild only (A and B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
```

The remaining cases are all fairly straightforward, given the meaning of `some` and `only`.  Though there are four class expressions, there are only two distinct classes.

```
(hasChild only (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
(hasChild some (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 1 Thing)
```

This is the class of things that have exactly one child, which must be an `A` or a `B`.

```
(hasChild only (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
(hasChild some (A or B)) and (hasChild exactly 2 Thing)
```

This is the class of things that have exactly two children, each of which must be an `A` or a `B`.

Comment: Thks a lot:) perfectly explained.