# the relation "is composed of" with protégé

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I want to create an ontology describing a process with Protégé. I have a concept "process" connected with 5 other concepts (process tasks) by the relationship "is_composed_of". How to express this in Protégé. Do I create an ObjectProperties and I specify the domain and range in this case I will have 5 relationship "is_composed_of".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is each instance of **Process** must be related to 5 instances of **ProcessTask** by the object property **isComposedOf**, then you'd use an axiom like:

**Process** ⊑ = 5 **isComposedOf**.**ProcessTask**

In the Manchester syntax, which is what you'd use in Protege, you'd go the **Process** class and add the following as a superclass:

isComposedOf **exactly** 5 ProcessTask

For more about quantified cardinality restrictions, see [Meaning of OWL exact cardinality restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137781/1281433).  [Defining cardinality of data property in OWL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24188632/1281433) include another example.

Comment: Thank you. 
I have another question: i want to create a recipe ontology for that i have 3 concepts (ingredient, recipe, utensil) for the concept ingredient i have two subclasses (dough, farce) which have subclasses like (sugar,butter,flour, etc). what to do for the class "sugar" for example which is a subclass of dough and also a subclass of farce?

Comment: @catty42 That design doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense, to be honest.  Sugar shouldn't be a subclass of dough, should it?  A cup of sugar isn't a cup of dough, after all.  When X is a subclass of Y, it means that if some individual e is an X, then e is also a Y.